# Organize a trade event || Business "speed dating" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matching

I'm Student of software engineering,
Right now I am working for my final project, scheduling Business matchmaking on a trade day.

The idea is to bring a **seller** (developer) and a **buyer** (A person with financial means) **together**. **The algorithm should be like "Speed Dating"**.

Let's say I have 15 tables and 10 sessions.
It means that each session 15 buyers will meet 15 sellers for 20 minutes.

**My question is how do I make the matching?**

Suppose each person has 8 attribute that characterize him.
•   I thinking creating bipartite graph (group A – Sellers, group B - Buyers)

•   Then link up between a seller and buyer based on similar attributes (Should consider what is level of error). dont want to bring together people who are not related

•   Then on each session look for a maximum matching.

Constraints: it's not a real time, I'll close registration a few days before the event.

I'm currently "idea blocked" on how to do the linking step (base on a person attributes).

I would appreciate your help,
Even a dialogue on the matter would help me a lot!:)

Comment: Could you use weighted bipartite matching (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs) where the weights are the number of similar attributes?

Comment: What attributes do you have to judge whether or not a seller and a buyer are "similar"?

Comment: 10x Khaelid i'm going to read about that.


Swordofpain - What I did not mentioned is that the event organizer (EO) should characterize this. EO will have a special permissions to create an event. he will then have to create a signing form for the following event.

In general, Suppose I have created an event, the event name is: "Software Solutions", a good form/attribute will have to be: Solution scope: video conferance, Social Network, etc. Recruiting Budget: >10000$,>100000$,etc.

The objective is: create a business "speed date" software.

Comment: @AviLevinshtein have you found a suitable algorithm for that? I'm looking for a similar solution.

Comment: @BartoszBlimke In fact, I found two
1. Hungarian algorithm of Kuhn, you can find lots of information about it. its very good to solve Bipartite matching.
2. A mix speed dateing soultion that looks not only for 2 group matching (boys girls) but also on n groups. for that you must read "Katz, B., Rutter, I., Strasser, B. and Wagner D., Speed dating, an algorithmic case study involving matching and scheduling (2011)" I talked with them and they used c++ lemon lib for thier work.

In terms of tools you have lemon for c++, and algs4.cs.princeton.edu which are tools for java to get you started.

Comment: @AviLevinshtein thank you, that's very useful! Strasser algorithm would be perfect, except the fact I have additional constraints. 1) there is a case when a seller can meet multiple buyers at once. 2) some buyers or sellers may not be available for some meeting rounds. This is difficult to represent with a graph.

Comment: Hi @BartoszBlimke, you can tweak the algorithm. regarding your first issue, you can implement a wrapper class which will be a client class and will hold a list of sellers or buyers. So in case of seller can meet multiple buyers, you can add multiple sellers objects with the same weights and then compute the result, the common ground for all sellers will be the client wrapper obj.
Regarding your second const, can you ask prior the matching step who will be unavailable on each round?
P.S - I got a Java implementation for the Hungarian algorithm, Let me know if you need it.

Comment: @AviLevinshtein thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately it's not that easy as we can only allow seller to meet buyers sharing some specified common attributes. I can't mix any buyers for the same meeting with one seller. Regarding second const, yes, I know upfront who is not available. With unavailabilities, iterating over rounds and applying Hungarian on each is doable (if not the 1st const) but Strasser algorithm is not going to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often given multi-dimensional data that describe data points, you define a similarity or "kernel" between points. This could be the e.g. dot product after you normalize by standard deviation in each dimension for example. Or it could be a Gaussian kernel e^((-d^2)/y) where d is the dot-product between points and y is a constant bandwidth parameter. Also e.g. if certain dimensions are categorical then you could the one-dimensional dot-product to be 1 if the categorical variables agree, otherwise 0. Then you can form the overall dot-product from the multi-dimensional data after normalizing each dimension by its standard deviation. The point is, once you form a similarity or kernel between points, then you can define a weighted bipartite graph where the weight of an edge is equal to the similarity/kernel between points, and your problem is to find a maximum weight matching. This is a well-known problem with solutions in the literature e.g. the Hungarian algorithm, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs .